# Cannot resolve symbols AttachToListView in Android (FloatingActionButton )

Tags: android

Выдает ошибку:Cannot resolve method AttachToListView.

Внутри onCreate:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabb);
        fab.attachToListView(lvMain);
        fab.setShadow(true);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: потому, что [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) не имеет метода `attachToListView` (как и метода `setShadow`). Если вы используете какие то сторонние библиотеки, то укажите ссылки на них.

Comment: Типа этого? import com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton;
import com.melnykov.fab.ObservableScrollView;
import com.melnykov.fab.ScrollDirectionListener;